# C# Access Modifier set to public but not accessible

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# project that references another project. The project that is being referenced has property settings. The property settings are set to public (I selected public in the drop down located on the Property settings in Visual Studio). I am able to access the properties of the project but when I type dot settings I get a red squigly underline... Settings is inaccessible due to it's pertection level. I have deleted and added the reference back in. What setting, other than the property settings drop down in VS, needs to be set to public in order to make the property settings public?

```
[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "15.7.0.0")]
internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

    private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

    public static Settings Default {
        get {
            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is it marked as an internal class?

Comment: also, you really should provide code as we can only guess

Comment: Show us the code will help people answer your question.

Comment: also make sure target framework is set correctly.

Comment: OK The class is internal sealed parial class Settings... and the method is public static.  Trying to figure out how to add code... It's too long for a comment

Comment: The frameworks are both 4.5.2

Comment: Open the designer of the settings file and choose `public` from dropdown. Default is `internal` so not accessible from outside the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Settings by default are

```
internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {
```

which makes them internal to the assembly.

If you want to expose them I'd make a wrapper class which exposes the individual settings you want to expose outside of your assembly.

Comment: Thank you Keith... I may need to do that

Comment: Notice that the Settings file properties also have a setting to toggle between public and internal